# The rules on how and when people can wear a cross

Tags: denomination-survey, tradition, symbolism, cross, human-body

Which principles govern the wearing of crosses? Do some denominations require that it touch the skin, or that it never be removed? Will a cross hung on the neck and one on an ear have different implications? Do any doctrines actually ban people from wearing a cross?

Comment: You need to ask for a particular denomination's take on this. Even then, I think it will be a matter of opinion and individual choice. Protestant denominations are likely to have no position.

Comment: @Mick My presumption here is that there aren't very many such rules. If I am wrong by all means vote to close.

Comment: Voting to close.  I think you need to ask Roman Catholics, Orthodox, or some specific denomination of Protestantism for an answer (if one exists).

Comment: @Abstractioniseverything. That is the way that this site works. It is not a discussion forum. The rules are very clear, and are designed to prevent inter-denominational and personal arguments.

Comment: Boy, is it going to be boring to ask the same question about Methodists, then Copts, then Mormons, then Calvinists, etc....

Comment: Well, you could try limiting it to denominations that have an official position on the practice, either for or against, and see what happens.

Comment: @Mick I wrote the question with that implication in mind, and perhaps it wasn't clear.

Comment: @guest37 I don't see any reason this question needs to  be scoped like that. Most branches of Christianity aren't even going to say anything about this at all, and the couple that do are fairly easily summarized with an eye to what the different stances are. One solid answer will take some effort but somebody with knowledge about this sort of practice across Christianity can reasonably be expected to answer this in the space of a single post.

Comment: @Mick Yes, that's the way this site generally works _BUT_ that's not a blanket rule to be applied blinding without considering the subject matter. We also allow overview questions if the range of the issue and wording of the question are such that it is reasonable for an answer to effectively cover all the bases. Unless you know something I don't, I suspect this issue doesn't  need that kind of break down. You said yourself one chunk doesn't have a position at all and I don't think there is going to be so many positions among the rest as to make this unanswerable.